# Issue with using a rate variable within a Monte-Carlo Simulation

Tags: distributions, simulation, monte-carlo

Apologies in advance is this is a complete n00b question.

I am a little new to Monte-Carlo Simulation, and not that crash hot at distribution fitting, but am wondering how to explain a particular issue with how to properly use Monte-Carlo Simulation over a Discrete Event Simulation model that has a rate variable in it (or maybe it's more general than that?) & what the appropriate solution is to the issue I'm thinking about.

A simple problem that demonstrates what I'm thinking about is simulating how long it takes, $d$ (days), to do a single task, $T$. So trivially, the duration is a function of the quantity of items to process, $Q$, and the rate of processing them, $r$ (items/day).

So the simulation model here is just $d = \frac{Q}{r}$, or perhaps $T_{\text{end_time}} = T_{\text{start_time}} + \frac{Q}{r}$

Now, say we have daily production data which gives us a series of $r$ values, and say we fit a normal distribution to that data which has a mean $\mu=5$ and $\sigma=1$

Now say $Q=100$, the expected mean of $d$ would be $\frac{100}{5}=20\text{ days}$.

The issue I see is in simply applying Monte-Carlo Simulation to this model though.

If I were to do 100 simulation runs of randomly drawn $r$ values and calculate $d$, the variance of the resulting $d$ values would be far greater than reality because a single random daily rate shouldn't be applied to 20 days. i.e, it is quite likely that you would get a day that has a rate of 3 items/day but very unlikely that you woudl get ~20 days in a row going at 3 items/day.

This seems like a pretty standard Monte-Carlo Simulation trap to fall for, but I can't seem to find the right language to describe it and search for to understand it properly.

My current solution to this is to draw ~20 random rates from the distribution, and either take their average and apply that within the model, or do some time-discretisation to model a day at a time. Which I believe are both appropriate solution approaches (as they do get the variance of $d$ down), but would love to know for sure if they are and what the right wording is around this issue

Comment: thinking out loud now, but is what I'm actually touching on more related to Discrete Event Simulation vs Discrete Rate Simulation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_rate_simulation